# Consistently change background image upon hovering over a link

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to have a row of Links and when the mouse hovers over one of the links, the background fades into the background image set to that link.

Lets say theres 5 links [Coke][Burger][Cow][Chicken][Dog]

when you load the webpage there is just the original background, but then when you hover over [Chicken] the background image changes to a chicken, then if you hover over [Coke] Theres the cocacola logo as the background.

I think you get the idea?

Comment: Yes, yes it is possible. But why use JavaScript when CSS can do this more simply?

Comment: @j08691 Nothing yet.

Just doing my layout first.

Comment: @DavidThomas I wasn't sure wether I should use JS or CSS. I guess I'll use CSS then.

Comment: -1 for having tried "Nothing yet"

Answer (score 0):

well, I would do that by css using ids (`#lnkCoke, #lnkBurger, etc.`) and the `:hover` pseude-class

but if you want to do it by javascript I would use  data attributes (`<a href="..." data-altBG="...">Coke</a>`) and mouse events (`onmouseover and onmouseout`) to change the background image

Comment: I'll give the CSS a try out. Just doing the main layout of my site now.